# How do you mount fluorescent strip lights on drywall?

Tags: electrical, lighting

How do you correctly mount and wire fluorescent strip lights to drywall? 
[image]

I've seen these on drywalled walls/ceilings before but never looked at how they get installed, other than there doesn't appear to be a junction box in the drywall.

I can imagine a lot of people just have their NM wire coming through a hole in the drywall, and then bring it into a knockout on the back and screw the fixture up, but does that meet code? Do you leave/make a hole big enough for a box connector to fit through?

What's the code-compliant way to install? What do you do prior to putting up drywall?

Answer (score 1):

The fixture itself is typically used as the junction box.  Just make sure to use a bushing or grommet to protect the cable where it enters the fixture.  These [Push in grommets](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Arlington-Industries-3-8-in-Black-Button-Plastic-Push-In-Connectors-25-Pack-NM94-25/100152865#.UbW3YPlwoiw) are useful for this.

[image: Push in grommet]